# Android:: Set max-length of EditText programmatically with other InputFilter

Tags: android

I'm using InputFilter like this to allow only alpha and numbers

```
private InputFilter[] inputFilters = new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter()
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
        {
            if (!Pattern.compile("[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890]*").matcher(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i))).matches())
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
} };
```

But problem is "android:maxLength" value in xml file is not working with this InputFilter

I think I need code in InputFilter to set max-length of EditText

Anyone has good idea for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just try this way

**InputFilter**

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
            {
                if (!Pattern.compile("[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890]*").matcher(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i))).matches())
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    };
```

**How to apply**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText edt =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt) ;

        edt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter,new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});


    }
```

Answer (score 158):

A simple one-liner would be:

`Java:`

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10) });
```

`Kotlin:`

```
myEditText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
```

Comment: This is so simply and feel this should get max votes.... and Come on top

Comment: Is there a way to run it programmatically?

Comment: This is very simple and efficient.

Answer (score 63):

```
public void setEditTextMaxLength(int length) {
    InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
    edt_text.setFilters(filterArray);
}
```

Comment: Great answer Deepak. A small thing to note here: If the user keeps on typing after the limit, it's keep getting stored into the buffer and thus the edittext suggestions keep building up bigger and bigger.

Comment: @shridutt-kothari why did you edit the answer? You changed it to my version. Leave it the way it was.

Comment: @Akeshwar we are defining the length of the filter, it should not overflow.

Answer (score 48):

> **For Kotlin**
>
> ```
> myEditText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))
> ```

Comment: It works perfectly for me in Kotlin, thank you very much

Answer (score 12):

If we want to limit the character input in an *EditText* , `EditText` in XML layout gives us **`android:maxLength`** to do this. But in java codes you might wonder why there isn't any **setMaxLength(int length) function**. The reason behind this is that when you want to restrict the EditText to accept certain value, you have to filter them and this would be invoked by setFilters. To make our EditText to have a fixed size we can use the following code.

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 3;
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
et.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Comment: Good answer with an explanation. And not just a mere copy pasted solution. Cheers!

Comment: greatly appreciate the explanation for why you need to use setFilters.

Answer (score 8):

Building on @Deepak's I used the following:

```
public void setEditTextMaxLength(final EditText editText, int length) {
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
    editText.setFilters(FilterArray);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
et.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(20))
```

in kotlin

Comment: Please **edit** your answer to provide an explanation. This is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow. But it's _especially_ useful here, where there are **nine** existing answers. What sets your answer apart? Under what circumstances would your answer be preferred over the existing approaches? Remember, each new answer adds another post people with this problem need to evaluate. Make it easier for them to understand the differences, and why they should consider your code over others.

Answer (score 6):

in kotlin

```
textInputEditText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function very very easy :

```
 public static void setEditTextMaxLength(EditText editText, int length) {
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
    editText.setFilters(FilterArray);
  }
```

and use this on your activity:

```
setEditTextMaxLength(edt_passcode, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this method:

```
private void setEditTextMaxLength(EditText et, int maxLength) {
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where you have more than one InputFilter, calling `textInputEditText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))` will set LengthFilter as the only InputFilter and replace the existing filter you have previously set.

To avoid this in Kotlin, you can add a new InputFilter to the existing InputFilter by doing the following:

```
textInputEditText.filters += InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)
```

This will preserve the existing InputFilter while adding another one. With this method, you can add as many InputFilters as possible.