# Set max length for EditText

Tags: android, maxlength

I want to set a 1 character length in EditText but just in one part of condition. There is a way to set max length via XML but this will be applied for the whole condition. How to set max length programmatically?

Comment: Looks like this answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24749916/5527154

Comment: it didn't help man

Comment: why android didn't make a a ready function for this

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have removed irrelevant java tag from question,pls use valid tags only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void setEditTextMaxLength(EditText editText, int length) {
      InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
      FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
      editText.setFilters(FilterArray);
  }
```

Comment: how to call it i saw this function and i gave it the EditText id and the length but nothing happened

Answer (score 8):

You can add this in your XML:

> android:maxLength="10"

or programmatically:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 3;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)
});
```

Comment: You put the first option in you .xml file (activity layout).
or
You put the second option in the activity file after 
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

it will be like this:

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

      EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
      int maxLength = 3;    
      editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
      new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)
      });
    }

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, this extension function is handy:

```
fun EditText.setMaxLength(maxLength: Int) {
    filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
edtTime.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4) });
```